# Almacenar imagen en base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, android-studio

Me encuentro con la situación que, he de mostrar mediante  una consulta a una base de datos MySQL en la nube una imagen en un tlf android, a través de un fichero PHP.

La duda es que no sé cuál es la mejor manera o más fácil de hacerlo, si guardando la imagen como blob o guardándola en la nube y en la base de datos hacer referencia a ella con un varchar. Imagino que sí la guardo como blob, tendré que serializarla y luego deserializarla, por eso imagino que es más fácil la segunda opción, agradecería cualquier comentario.

Comment: Ambas opciones son viables, cada una con sus ventajas y desventajas. En la mayoría de casos se opta por almacenar en ficheros y la ruta en bd, pero todo depende de los requerimientos y necesidades. Las respuestas a esta pregunta tal y como está redactada tienden a estar basadas en opiniones.

Comment: Hola Las Perseidas. Esta pregunta se basa en opiniones porque pides recomendaciones en cuanto a qué opcion usar. Te sugiero que tú valores las opciones y si tienes problemas concretos en la implementacion, preguntar aqui siguiendo [ask]. Mira [help/on-topic] para saber sobre qué preguntar aqui. Cuando tengas 20 de rep, podrás entrar en el chat donde las preguntas basadas en opiones son validas. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es un tema de decisiones sobre performance y tamaño de base de datos que deberás evaluar.

Yo suelo usar un Varchar. ¿Porqué?

1. He realizado algunas pruebas y no he visto mejoras en rendimiento en alojarlo en la base.
2. La base queda más pesada usando blob o longblob.
3. Suelo hacer procesos con las imágenes una vez dentro del servidor para achicarlas, etc.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Hola Martín. Gracias por tu aportacion pero recuerda que las preguntas que son basadas en opinioes no son validas y por tanto no deberian responderse. En ese caso, han de ser reportadas para su cierre. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendación. La tendré en cuenta.